# Could not find a class for RallyJiraCommentLinker

Tags: jira, rally, jira-plugin

Using RallyConnectorforJira-Ruby-2.7.4 I'm trying to configure the connector to sync comments between Rally and JIRA as documented at http://www.rallydev.com/help/Jira-config-RallyJiraCommentLinker.pxml , but when I add the following to my jira_config.xml:

```
<RelatedObjectLinkers>
  <RallyJiraCommentLinker />
</RelatedObjectLinkers>
```

the connector dies immediately after startup with a "Related Object Linker could not find a class for RallyJiraCommentLinker" error (log contents below).

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is the RallyJiraCommentLinker no longer supported?

Thanks,

Andrew.

--- Begin Log ---

```
************************************************************************************************************

 rally2_jira_connector
     pid: 1234
     starting at: 2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z
     cwd: /opt/RallyConnectorforJira-Ruby-2.7.4
     configs: jira_config.xml
     interval: 15

************************************************************************************************************
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z]   ANY : ConnectorRunner.block in run - processing to commence using content from jira_config.xml
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z]  INFO : Class.read_config_file - jira_config.xml last modified 2012-08-15 15:06:45 UTC, size: 2665 chars
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z]  INFO : RallyConnection.initialize - Initializing Rally connection version 2.7.4
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z]  INFO : RallyConnection.initialize - Rally Web Services version 1.16
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z]  INFO : JiraConnection.initialize - Initializing JIRA connection version 2.7.4
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z]  INFO : Class.read_workflow_file - jira_workflow.xml
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Connector.rescue in block in read_related_object_linkers - Related Object Linker could not find a class for RallyJiraCommentLinker
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : ConnectorRunner.initialize - uninitialized constant Kernel::RallyJiraCommentLinker
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.exception - Message uninitialized constant Kernel::RallyJiraCommentLinker
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.exception - Stack Trace
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector.rb:364:in `const_get'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector.rb:364:in `block in read_related_object_linkers'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector.rb:362:in `read_related_object_linkers'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector.rb:54:in `read_config'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector.rb:37:in `initialize'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector_runner.rb:154:in `new'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector_runner.rb:154:in `block in run'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector_runner.rb:136:in `each'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/yeti-2.7.4/lib/yeti/connector_runner.rb:136:in `run'
[2012-08-15 15:08:02 Z] ERROR : Object.block in exception - rally2_jira_connector.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

--- End Log ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we actually introduced that very recently in the 2.8.1 version of the connector so it's just not in the version you have.  hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, OK. How can I get hold of 2.8.1? The downloads at http://www.rallydev.com/help/jira-installation-user-guide list 2.8.0 as the latest version available for download.

Comment: We should have it posted by early next week - sorry I had thought it was up.

Comment: Cheers Dave, just checked again today and 2.8.1 is now available so I'll give that version a try. Thanks, Andrew.